# Proving a collection of sets is a partition within a surjective function

Tags: functions, discrete-mathematics, set-partition

I am trying to solve the following problem:

Let *A* and *B* be sets and let *f:A→B* be a surjective function. For each *b∈ B*, let $A_b=(f^{-1}) (\{b\})$. Prove that the collection of sets $\{A_b | b\in B\}$ is a partition of *A*.

I understand that in order for something to be a partition of a set, it must be pairwise disjoint and that $\cup A_b=A$ is also a requirement. I also know that since the function is surjective, *A* has more elements than *B* and $f(A)=B$. However, I'm having trouble figuring out how to form this information into a cohesive proof.

Comment: You've stated what you need to prove: pairwise disjointness and exhaustion. To see pairwise disjointness, suppose $b\neq b'$ and show that $A_b\cap A_{b'}=\emptyset$. (Suppose for contradiction the intersection weren't empty. What goes wrong?) To see exhaustion, take $a\in A$. Then consider $b:=f(a)$; we have $a\in A_b$.

Answer (score 0):

- Given $b,b'\in B$, $b\neq b'$, suppose that there exists $x\in A_b\cap A_{b'}$. Then : $b=f(x)=b'$, a contradiction ! Hence $A_b\cap A_{b'}=\emptyset$.
- For any $b\in B$, there exists $a\in A$ such that $f(a)=b$ because $f$ is surjective. Then $a\in (f^{-1})(\{b\})$ and we conclude that $A_b\neq\emptyset$.
- Finally $A\subset\bigcup_{b\in B}A_b$ because each $x\in A$ belongs to $A_{f(x)}$. And the converse inclusion is trivial.